# Display seconds in addition to hours and minutes on the Clock

Tags: iphone, clock

How would I go about getting the clock on my iPhone to display the seconds beside the minutes?

I have looked at *Settings → General → Date & Time*, but it only allows me to choose a Time Zone, Set the clock automatically or toggle 24-Hour Time.

Is there anything I can do to cause the clock to display seconds in addition to minutes and hours?

Comment: Does the included Clock application fit the bill?

Comment: I hadn't thought to check that, I had a look and I've found that the Clock application doesn't show seconds, I've tried to find the settings for it to see if that can be changed but I can't see to locate them, are they there?

Comment: oops. maybe the upcoming OS ;)

Comment: I just checked my wife's iPhone 4. She also has the clock app. It is showing seconds in the World clock section. I'll look to see if there are other ways.

Comment: @DavidDelMonte I've just noticed that the world clocks have a red hand ticking for seconds, but there isn't a numeric value. What I'm really trying to achieve is to change the clock that is displayed at the top and also when the phone is locked so that it shows seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anything I can do to cause the clock to display seconds in addition to minutes and hours?

In the default, non-jailbroken OS? I don't think so.

In the status bar on a jailbroken iPhone? Yes. It's called [StatusBarSeconds](http://www.ijailbreak.com/cydia/statusbarseconds-cydia-tweak/).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the icon for the Clock app on your home screen it has a moving second hand. For most cases this is sufficient for me.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

As they say there is an App for that.  Here is one I found:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/emerald-time/id290384375?mt=8

Comment: This doesn't address the question by the OP.

Answer (score -4):

If u want to time 90 seconds set it to 2 minutes then run it down to 1 min 30 secs. Hit pause.  Now u can run 90 secs.